# Implementing a scala method using a partial function

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I have a class, as follows:

```
trait Foo {
  def greet(name: String) : String
}

trait Bar {
  def hello(name: String) = s"Hello ${name}!"
}

class Greeter extends Foo with Bar {
  def greet(name: String) = hello(name)
}
```

I'm curious if it is possible to implement `greet` using a partial application of the `hello` method? Something like:

```
class Greeter extends Foo with Bar {
  def greet = hello
}
```

(Obviously this doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can certainly implement `greet`, as noted by @chris, that code snippet *overloads* `Foo.greet(name:String)`; it does not *override* it:

```
class Greeter extends Foo with Bar {
    def greet = hello _
}

<console>:9: error: class Greeter needs to be abstract, since method
       greet in trait Foo of type (name: String)String is not defined
       class Greeter extends Foo with Bar { def greet = hello _ }
```

While the following does compile:

```
class Greeter extends Foo with Bar {
    def greet(name: String) = hello(name)
    def greet = hello  _
}
```

---

As an aside, you can also define `greet` with an explicit type decl, without the trailing underscore:

```
def greet: String=> String = hello
```

Comment: So, in summary, it's not possible to do this unless the super class had already defined the method as String => String, rather than (name: String)String. Interesting that `def greet(name: String) = hello(name)` and `def greet = hello _` are not the same, despite having the same name and effective type of String => String, and that one can define both in the same class. Haskell 1, Scala 0. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Scala you often have to explicitly state when you want to apply a method only partially. This is done by writing an underscore behind the method name (but do not forget a space before that). In your case it would work as follows:

```
def greet = hello _
```

**EDIT:** After what @Richard Sitze observed, you could amend the situation by slightly changing the definition of `Foo` as follows:

```
trait Foo {
  def greet : String => String
}
```

Whether this is appropriate of course depends on your specific setup.